# displaying mean with sem or confidence interval

Tags: statistics

When I look at scientific papers, bar charts I usually come to see are shown with mean +/- sem.

As stated [here](https://egret.psychol.cam.ac.uk/statistics/local_copies_of_sources_Cardinal_and_Aitken_ANOVA/errorbars.htm),

> When standard error (SE) bars do not overlap, you cannot be sure that
>   the difference between two means is statistically significant

and

> If 95% CI error bars do not overlap, you can be sure the difference is
>   statistically significant (P < 0.05).

Even if the reverse is not true, why don't we always use the confidence interval instead of the sem in bar charts, since it seems more informative ?

Comment: This question is probably more suitable at Cross Validate.

Comment: Actually, it's also on Cross Validated, but I think it belongs to Academia also (and as I thought, answers are a little more relevant here)

Comment: Oh... that's naughty. Users do not like cross posting here. :) You should perhaps delete this question.

Comment: I know, but I really od think my question is about stastistical validity as much as scientific publicability, so it should belong to both, don't you agree ?

Comment: So-called "dynamite plots" (bar plots with whiskers - no matter what the whiskers represent) are rather disliked by statisticians, since they compress (that is, lose) information more than alternatives while falling prey to perceptual problems. See [here](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/DynamitePlots) and [here](http://emdbolker.wikidot.com/blog:dynamite).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a proper answer would require a too technical discussion and would be largely beyond the scope of Academia.SE. Even the premise "If 95% CI error bars do not overlap, you can be sure the difference is statistically significant (P < 0.05)" is questionable in many experimental situations, but discussing this would really bring us too far.

Comment: Even if you have some points, I really don't understand the need to close topics like this one, that's not like it could do anything wrong, and so far I got some interesting answers... I don't understand the "too far" concept neither, if someone doesnt want to answer, they don't and that's it... Also, my post on Cross Validated didn't get the same answers, so basicaly by closing this topic you really prevent me from getting a good answer.

Comment: See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Answer (score 1):

My guess: SEM needs to be multiplied with the constant from the probability distribution of concern (e.g. t-distribution) to become confidence interval. In some study, sample size is so low that the constant can make the bars look huge.

Yet, in your cited link there is another important phrase:

> No surprises here. When SE bars overlap, (as in experiment 2) you can
>   be sure the difference between the two means is not statistically
>   significant (P>0.05).

So, SE may not serve to tell if there is a significance difference, but can tell if there is likely none. Depending on the researchers' motive this could be a good feature.

What I'd advocate, however, is not to believe these visual comparison as if they are definitive. One illustrative explanation can be found in this online [pdf](https://www.cscu.cornell.edu/news/statnews/stnews73.pdf).

Anyhow, a graph is a graph and as long as it's labeled clearly I'd consider that acceptable. What can confuse people is when the authors use this kind of error-bar like device but did not footnote what the bars represent.

Comment: So if SE bars overlap, it's definitively not significant and if CI bars dont overlap, it's definitively significant. Others possibilities are unsure. Am I right ?